# 2d trig integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, trigonometric-integrals

From one of the maths seminar course introduction to calculus for the first year students @King math's school of academic.

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm dx \mathrm dy}{\left(\frac{\tan x}{\sin y}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sin x}{\cos y}\right)^2}=-\frac{\pi}{15}$$

I try several days to simplify this but, couldn't.

Can anyone show how this is done to get to the result proposed?

Comment: How can the integral of a positive function be negative? Offhand, this improper integral may not even be convergent.

Comment: The integral over $x$ does indeed diverge at the lower limit. If you replace the tangent by a cosine, however, you will get a really nice result.

Comment: What is more astounding is that the right hand side is $-\frac {\Gamma(4)\zeta(4)}{\pi^3}$